# does anyone know much about python class? and its objects is giving me errors when i input some data

Tags: python, class, inheritance, subclass

[image: built a class i get this error when i run the code]

if unit == 'F': self.number = (number - 32) * 5/9
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'number' referenced before assignment

Comment: Please include code as Text and not as an image and include the full traceback error.

Comment: You haven't defined ```number``` in the ```to``` method's parameter list.  Though judging from your intention,  you should have a ```self.number = number``` in your ```__init__``` constructor and then refer to ```self.number``` instead of ```number```.  Assuming that's what you wanted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

number variable need to be declare first at the beginning of to() function.
A simple : " number; " in first line of your to() function will solve the problem.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

```
class Temp:
    """A class to help work with lengths in various units"""
    number = 0
    def __init__(self, number, unit='C'):
        # Convert and store Temp as self.temp
        if unit == 'C': self.temp = number
        elif unit == 'F': self.temp = (number - 32) * 5/9
        elif unit == 'K': self.temp = number + 273.15
        # Unit not recognised
        else: raise Exception("Unit not recognised")
    
    def to(self, unit, dp=None):
        
        # Convert self.temp to unit
        if unit == 'C': number = (5/9 * self.temp ) + 32
        elif unit == 'C': number = self.temp - 273.15 
        
        else: raise Exception("Unit not recognised")
        if dp: number = round(number, dp)
        return f"{number}{unit}"
    
    def __str__(self):
        return f"Temp: {self.temp}C"
    
    def __add__(self, other):
        return Length(self.metres + other.metres)
```